# How can I return multiple strings from a contract function?

Tags: solidity, contract-design, contract-development, contract-invocation, string

In solidity it's obvious how to get a single string returned from a function. But, I'd like to have the smart contract return multiple string values. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 33):

There are a few types of string values that you may be referring to.

- `bytes1` - `bytes32`: fixed size.
- `bytes` or `string`: dynamically sized.

Solidity supports functions with multiple return values.

```
contract MultiReturner {
    function getData() constant returns (bytes32, bytes32) {
        bytes32 a = "abcd";
        bytes32 b = "wxyz";
        return (a, b);
    }

    function getDynamicData() constant returns (bytes, bytes) {
        bytes a;
        a.push('a');
        a.push('b');
        a.push('c');
        bytes b;
        b.push('x');
        b.push('y');
        b.push('z');
        return (a, b);
    }
}
```

You can do the same with `bytes` or `string` but with the limitation that solidity does not support returning dynamically sized values to other functions.  This means that you would be able to use the `getData` function from within another contract and retrieve the return values but you would not be able to retrieve the return values from `getDynamicData` from within a contract.

```
contract UsesMultiReturner {
    function doIt() {
        mr = MultiReturner(0x1234);

        // this will work
        var (a, b) = mr.getData();

        // this won't work
        var (a, b) = mr.getDynamicData();
    }
}
```

You can however retrieve the return values from both `getData` and `getDynamicData` when `call` from outside of the blockchain.

Comment: since returned type is `bytes32`, should we typecast `var` into `bytes32`?@Piper Merriam.

Comment: In solidity `var` can be used to delegate selecting the appropriate type to the compiler.  `a` and `b` will be set as `bytes32` by the compiler since the compiler knows that `mr.getData()` will return type `(bytes32, bytes32)`

Comment: `var` is now deprecated.  Is there an update on how to return multiple values using `0.4.21`?

Comment: Solidity [0.4.23](https://github.com/digitaldonkey/ethereum-php/blob/dev/tests/TestEthClient/test_contracts/contracts/MultiReturner.sol), but I'm not sure if it actually does the same thing.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Seriality](https://github.com/pouladzade/Seriality) library. [Seriality](https://github.com/pouladzade/Seriality) is a library for serializing and de-serializing all the Solidity types in a very efficient way which mostly written in solidity-assembly

1- By means of Seriality you can easily serialize and deserialize your variables, structs, arrays, tuples, ... and pass them through the contracts and libraries.

2- You can decouple your contract from libraries by serializing parameters into a byte array.

3- It also can be used as an alternative for RLP protocol in Solidity.

Here is a sample :

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.16;

import "./Seriality.sol";

contract StringsReturn is Seriality {

function stringCaller() public returns( string memory out1,
                                        string memory out2,
                                        string memory out3,
                                        string memory out4,
                                        string memory out5)
                                        {

    bytes memory buffer = new bytes(320);
    uint offset = stringCallee(buffer);

    //deserializing
    out1 = new string (getStringSize(offset, buffer));
    bytesToString(offset, buffer, bytes(out1));
    offset -= sizeOfString(out1);

    out2 = new string (getStringSize(offset, buffer));
    bytesToString(offset, buffer, bytes(out2));
    offset -= sizeOfString(out2);

    out3 = new string (getStringSize(offset, buffer));
    bytesToString(offset, buffer, bytes(out3));
    offset -= sizeOfString(out3);

    out4 = new string (getStringSize(offset, buffer));
    bytesToString(offset, buffer, bytes(out4));
    offset -= sizeOfString(out4);

    out5 = new string (getStringSize(offset, buffer));
    bytesToString(offset, buffer, bytes(out5));

}

function stringCallee(bytes memory buffer) public returns (uint buffer_size) {

    string memory out1  = new string(32); 
    string memory out2  = new string(32);        
    string memory out3  = new string(32);
    string memory out4  = new string(32);        
    string memory out5  = new string(32);

    out1 = "Come on baby lets dance!";
    out2 = "May I buy you a drink?";
    out3 = "I am an itinerant programmer";
    out4 = "Inam javab lashi!";
    out5 = "Bia inja dahan service";

    // Serializing
    buffer_size =  sizeOfString(out5) +
                   sizeOfString(out4) + 
                   sizeOfString(out3) + 
                   sizeOfString(out2) +
                   sizeOfString(out1);

    uint offset = buffer_size;

    stringToBytes(offset, bytes(out1), buffer);
    offset -= sizeOfString(out1); 

    stringToBytes(offset, bytes(out2), buffer);
    offset -= sizeOfString(out2);

    stringToBytes(offset, bytes(out3), buffer);
    offset -= sizeOfString(out3); 

    stringToBytes(offset, bytes(out4), buffer);
    offset -= sizeOfString(out4); 

    stringToBytes(offset, bytes(out5), buffer);

    return buffer_size;
  }    
}
```

This is the output of stringCaller()

```
"0": "string: out1 Come on baby lets dance!",
"1": "string: out2 May I buy you a drink?",
"2": "string: out3 I am an itinerant programmer",
"3": "string: out4 Inam javab lashi!",
"4": "string: out5 Bia inja dahan service"
```

And here is the buffer :

```
    42696120696e6a6120646168616e207365727669636500000000000000000000
    0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000016
    496e616d206a61766162206c6173686921000000000000000000000000000000
    0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000011
    4920616d20616e206974696e6572616e742070726f6772616d6d657200000000
    000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001c
    4d617920492062757920796f752061206472696e6b3f00000000000000000000
    0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000016
    436f6d65206f6e2062616279206c6574732064616e6365210000000000000000
    0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000018
```