# Contract reading a string returned by another contract

Tags: solidity, contract-design, evm, contract-invocation, string

I have 2 contracts, `Parents` and `Child` which has a  public string variable - `name`.

```
contract Child {
    string public name;
    function child (string _name){
       name = _name;
    }
}
```

`Parents` needs to get that name:

```
contract Parents {
    string public childName;
    Child child;
    function Parents(address _childAddress){
        child = Child(_childAddress);
        childName = child.name();  // I also tried child.name
    }
}
```

But I'm getting the following error:

```
Error: Type tuple() is not implicitly convertible to expected type string storage ref.
        childName = child.name();
```

So I've tried to create another function in `Child` that will return a string:

```
function getName() returns (string name) {
    return name;
}
```

And in `Parents` I've changed

```
childName = child.name();  into--->  childName = child.getName();
```

But I keep getting the same error. Any ideas?
As always, your help is appreciated.

Answer (score 12):

**Variable-sized data that is returned by one contract, cannot be read by another contract.**

`Parents` is trying to read a [`string`](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/latest/types.html#dynamically-sized-byte-array) from `Child` and thus the error.

[Reference:](https://github.com/ethereum/solidity/issues/164#issuecomment-149846605)

> The EVM is unable to read variably-sized data from external function
>   calls... Note that on the other hand, it is [possible to return
>   variably-sized data](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/632/how-can-i-return-multiple-strings-from-a-contract-function), it just cannot be read from within the EVM.

[EIP 5](https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/blob/master/EIPS/eip-5.md) is a [proposed](https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/issues/8) update of the EVM that's [needed](https://github.com/ethereum/solidity/issues/166#issuecomment-154405118) to allow contracts to read dynamically-sized data returned by other contracts.

Comment: is this still the case as i think this works now. i am in solidity 0.8.17. can you confirm?

Answer (score 3):

Here is a version that compiles.

As the `address` type is more easily converted into the `string` type, I've stored the original addresses as the `address` types, and added a function to convert from `address` to `string` when required.

```
contract Child {
    address public addr;

    function child (address _addr) {
        addr = _addr;
    }    

    function getAddress() returns (address) {
        return addr;
    }

    function toBytes(address x) returns (bytes b) {
        b = new bytes(20);
        for (uint i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
            b[i] = byte(uint8(uint(x) / (2**(8*(19 - i)))));
        }
    }

    function getName() returns (string) {
        return string(toBytes(addr));
    }
}

contract Parents {
    address public childAddr;
    Child child;

    function Parents(address _childAddress) {
        child = Child(_childAddress);
        childAddr = child.getAddress();
    }
}
```

I have stored all addresses as the `address` type.

I have added the function `toBytes(...)` to convert from the `address` type to the `bytes` type (from [How to convert an address to bytes in Solidity?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/884/how-to-convert-an-address-to-bytes-in-solidity)).

And you can easily convert from `bytes` to `string` by casting using `string(...)`.

Comment: This will not work if your string has more than 20 bytes. But you can use bytes32, for 32 bytes!