# How can i return a dynamic number of values

Tags: solidity, contract-development, contract-design, contract-invocation

i have consulted this thread:
[How can I return multiple strings from a contract function?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/632/how-can-i-return-multiple-strings-from-a-contract-function)

but i cant find a way to adapt it, as the number of variables i need to return is not set.

here is my top 10 PhD certified code:

```
mapping (uint256=>string)  fieldNameArr; //filled in another function
function getAllFields()  public view returns (string){
    uint g;
    for(g=0;g<=e ;g++){

        arr.push(bytes(fieldNameArr[g]));
        arr.push(",");

    }  
return (arr);
}
```

Remix is returning an error regarding the type, but i have tried a lot of tricks to solve this and i can't find a way.

Please ask for precision if you need any.
Thank you for your help.

Comment: You can't, it is not possible in solidity.

Comment: Note that as of Solidity 0.4.22 this _is_ possible: https://github.com/ethereum/solidity/releases/tag/v0.4.22

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible to return (yet) a dynamic amount of values in solidity. In particular arrays. It is said in the documentation. Check this: http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.4.21/control-structures.html?highlight=multiple%20return#returning-multiple-values